# Change date format in echo function

Tags: php, sql

I have created a query which works fine, I just have a problem with this two dates which are "echoed" :

```
echo "du : $item->session_du | ";
echo "au : $item->session_au<br /><br />";
```

Echo are displaying the date in the following format :

> 2016-01-11 23:00:00

I need the output in this format

> lundi 11 janvier 2016

I haven't found a way to do it so I would appreciate if someone could advise me how to solve this issue.

Query :

```
$candidateid = JRequest::getVar('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment___id');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $query = $db->getQuery(true);
   $query
      ->select (array('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id', 'gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.nom_formation', 'gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.intitule_session', 'gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.session_du', 'gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.session_au'))   
  ->from('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment')
  ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation ON gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id = gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation.parent_id')
  ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat ON gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment_repeat_choix_formation.choix_formation = gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.id')
  ->leftJoin('gprh_fabrik_user_training ON gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.parent_id = gprh_fabrik_user_training.id')
  ->having('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id = ' . $db->quote($candidateid))
  ->group('gprh_fabrik_user_enrollment.id, gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.nom_formation, gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.intitule_session, gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.session_du, gprh_fabrik_user_training_124_repeat.session_au');
   $db->setQuery($query);
   $row = $db->loadObjectList();
   echo "<div style='font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;'><OL>";
   foreach ($row as $item)
   {
       echo "<LI> $item->nom_formation | ";
       echo "$item->intitule_session | ";
       echo "du : $item->session_du | ";
       echo "au : $item->session_au<br /><br />";
       echo "</LI>";
   }
   echo "</OL></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To translate the date to another language, you can do this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
// with $item->session_du = "2016-01-11 23:00:00"
print strftime('du : %A %d %B %Y', strtotime($item->session_du));
```

Will output:

```
lundi 11 janvier 2016
```

strtotime() takes a date string and return a timestamp, strftime() takes that timestamp and apply a format, returning a string based in the setlocale() configuration.

More details, here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Hi CJ Nimes, Thank you for your reply. I was aware about the strftime function I just don't know how to put it in my above query code. Would appreciate if you could show me how, since i'm stuck.

Comment: Just add setlocale() at the beginning of the script, and strftime() in the corresponding echos. If this works for you, please mark the answer as accepted! :)

Comment: I tried several methods to add it in the echo string, but it doesn't work. Last test was : echo "au : strftime('%A %d %B %Y', strtotime($item->session_du)) | "; If you know how to do it, would it be to much to ask you to show me how ?

Comment: dont put quotes around the functions, they never will be called. I've edited my answer adding "du : " inside the strftime first argument. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since your using an object orientated approch you really should use the `DateTime` class and `IntlDateFormatter`.

You can use a the same formatter for any dates you have as long as it's declared before it's used.

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::LONG);

$dt = new DateTime($item->session_du);
echo "du : {$formatter->format($dt)} | ";
```